# My Windows Service can't start

Tags: c#, windows-services

I developed one windows service in c#. In this service i add one DLL. My service running fine till yesterday.How ever when i start my service from task manager it's give me error

> The service did not respond to the start or control request in a
>   timely fashion.

When i search this error and I found one solution that give "`ServicesPipeTimeout`"  in registry but it also not working. I also restart my PC but it's also not work.

**When I see the event Log It's give me the detail**

> Faulting application name: CronService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time
>   stamp: 0x556d42ac Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version:
>   6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52158f2d Exception code: 0xe0434352

Can give me proper solution for this?

Comment: Have you checked Event Viewer -> Windows Logs -> Application -> Errors for any unhandled exceptions the service is throwing?

Comment: I can't find windows log in Event viewr. In event viewer four panel is there 1)overview 2) summary 3)recently view nodes 4) Log summery.

Comment: In the left hand panel there should be some folders; Custom Views, Windows Logs, etc

Comment: **EVENT LOG DETAIL**  Faulting application name: CronService.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x556d42ac Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.3.9600.16384, time stamp: 0x52158f2d Exception code: 0xe0434352

Comment: Are you sure it is related to your service?

Comment: It's give application name "CronService.exe" so i found that

Comment: another log is **The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.** but why this happen I don't know

Comment: Debug your service to find out the root cause. Here is the msdn link on how to debug a window service https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The usual reason is service constructor is taking a lot of time to initialize. Your service was running fine till yesterday, so you need to investigate what has added to the delay. As RagtimeWilly suggested, the first thing to check is the eventviewer.
It would help if you can add your code and eventviewer details.

You can debug your service with a console application and check what is causing this delay.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall your windows service and then install it again. It may works.

Answer (score 0):

Check for lengthy operations in your services startup/ construction code. Also add some logging so you know what's happening.